Hungarian method with maximum cost constraint
I'm using the Hungarian method (in Python via scipy.optimize.linear_sum_assignment) to find the optimal pairing between two 2D point sets $A$ and $B$ by minimizing the square distances between pairs. However, I have an extra constraint that two points can't be a pair if the distance between them exceeds some threshold $M$.
Right now I'm implementing this as follows:

Compute cost matrix $D$ as $D_{jk} = d(A_j, B_k)$ where $d$ is the square distance between two points.
Produce a set of pairings using the Hungarian method.
Remove all pairs $(j,k)$ where $D_{jk} > M^2$.

However, this does not produce optimal results. The best way I can explain it is that filtering the points after finding the pairings leaves unpaired points that potentially could have been better matches in step 2.
For example, here are two sets of 3 points with a non-optimal pairing, produced from the above algorithm:

This shows two sets of three points where the topmost blue point was matched with the bottom right orange point but filtered out in step 3.
However, this would've been a better match:

Even though that is not the minimal total cost, it is the minimal total cost without exceeding the distance constraint.
My question is: How can I apply the Hungarian method (or something like it) while also taking a maximum cost constraint into account?

If two points can't be paired when they are more than distance $M$ apart, you should be able to initialize the “distance” between those points to be $\infty$ instead of their actual distance.

@SteveKass Thanks; I tried that but the problem is if a given point is over $M$ from all other points, it puts an entire row or column of $\infty$ in $D$, which breaks the algorithm because all pairings end up with $\infty$ cost. However, I got it working with a similar strategy of just assigning a really large but still finite cost to the points in question, and then filtering out pairs with that cost afterwards. Thanks!

If you have any such "isolated" points, you can just omit them from the problem.

@RobPratt Yeah, that's the right solution, but I was trying to avoid the implementation / computational overhead of removing rows and columns from a matrix after the fact.

PS if anybody is wondering what number I used; these are 2D points in an image with finite dimensions $W$x$H$, so I used $W^2+H^2$ as the "special" value (it's the max possible squared distance between two points). I didn't want to use the maximum floating-point value because I didn't want to introduce the potential for floating-point magnitude errors into the cost calculations.
